# Comparison between string cell to list cell in python

Tags: python, string, list, debugging, comparison

```
def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
i = 0
new_string = ""
while i < len(secret_word):
    j = 0
    print(1)
    for j in old_letters_guessed:
        if secret_word[i] == old_letters_guessed[j]:
            new_string += secret_word[i]
        print(old_letters_guessed[j])
        j += 1
    print(secret_word[i])
    i += 1
return new_string
```

Why the comparate between those string don't work?And can someone help to fix it?

Comment: while int(choice) != 9:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. You can convert the input to int or 9 to string '9'

```
choice = input('Enter an option - out of the loop')
while int(choice) != 9:  #or while choice != '9'
    menu(list_of_products, choice)
    choice = input('Enter an option - in the loop')
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe choice is a string and you need to convert it to int.